# How can I derive a metric comparing two 2D laser scans quantitatively, WITHOUT using any scan matching techniques?

Tags: mobile-robot, slam, laser, probability

TLDR version: I have two laser scans taken at the same pose that align nearly completely (see image). I want to come up with a metric that can quantify how well one did as opposed to the other.

Longer version:
Hello, I have two 2D laser scans at the same pose. One is [simulated](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/occupancy_grid_utils/blob/25c77f6abea9b0124cd4bc2b15a822653f45c624/include/occupancy_grid_utils/ray_tracer.h#L62C13-L62C13) using a known pose and occupancy grid map. The second is the raw scan from the laser scanner. They look like this:

[image: Comparing simulated scan to the real scan]

These points are in cartesian coordinates only for representation, but the scan is naturally in polar coordinates; so a range value at each angle step.

Now, I want to find some sort of a normalised metric that can say for example "the sim. scan has a match of 0.95 with the real scan".

I first tried to evaluate each range from the simulated scan with a Gaussian function centered around the corresponding range from the real scan. The function would look like:
$$g(x; \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left\{ -0.5 \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2} \right\}$$

Then, ideally, I would have multiplied the values for each range and arrived at a metric that quantifies the simulated scan against the real scan. Though the problem is, depending on the variance that I set $g(x)$ could be any value that is not contained within $1$. For example, for $\mu = 5$, $x = 4.9$, $g(x) = 2.4197$ for $\sigma^2 = 0.01$ and $g(x) = 1.2$ for $\sigma^2 = 0.1$.

And rightly so, the Gaussian function does not give me a probability value when evaluated at a point. To get the probability, I need to integrate it in an interval. As the interval gets smaller, the probability goes to $0$.

And I wonder, the literature should have something related to this problem already. But I did not come across anything related to "comparing two 2d laser scans", that does involve scan matching (or maybe I am not searching well enough). Any directions to tackle this would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Edit: some information for the motivation behind this:
The aim is to detect faults in a laser scanner using a previously built map and trajectory estimate. This is to see if I can compare two scans that should be nearly the same in the ideal case, and if they are not, this could be indicative of a fault. I am aware that this approach assumes a few things that cannot always be given. But given a well mapped area in normally functioning robot, I want to investigate if this idea could be used. The simulated scan comes in picture when you know you are at a known location with a previously built map available, then you can generate what the scan could look like in theory.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics, Shrinivas Iyengar. I'm not sure how you're going to say `the sim. scan has a match of 0.95 with the real scan` with an algorithm that `does not involve scan matching.` Have you looked at iterative closest point algorithms? What units are you expecting a `0.95 match` to mean? How would you do this by hand for any two scans?

Comment: Hi @Chuck thanks for your reply. So, I am trying to find some sort of a similarity score. ICP techniques would give me a relative transformation, but I fail to understand how I can use that matrix in a way that gives me any indication how well the simulated scan did. As you can see the simulated scan module did really well, but  I would like to attach a normalised numeric value to it.

Comment: `How would you do this by hand for any two scans?`

That is what I am here to find out. After some searching I found out that I could use some point-to-point distance metric. So find an initial correspondence between the points and find the distance between point pairs. But i do not know what to do after that? Sum them up? And I do not know how to normalise them. 

As you can see, I am making this up as I go 

Comment: This is the point in a project where a [literature review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature_review) is helpful. What research have you done so far for evaluating correspondence between two point clouds? The [Wikipedia article on point set registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration) is pretty extensive and has a very long list of [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration#References) at the bottom.

Comment: What you use as a metric is up to you, and even that is not clearly defined in the problem statement here. Do you actually want to measure the translation and rotation difference between the point clouds? Are you just looking for a singular value like [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) or [r squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) like a line fit value? The metric(s) you need will be driven by what you intend to do with the result, so it's important to think critically about your project and read how others have approached the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, these are good pointers for me. I have updated the question to add the information for why I am asking such a question.
As for the research I found some papers talking about the quality of point cloud alignment: [Analyzing the quality of matched 3D point clouds of objects](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8206584) (has some flaws), [CorAl – Are the point clouds Correctly Aligned?](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9568846) (still reading it). I found it hard to find papers that talk about how well two scans are aligned (maybe just my own shortcomings).

Comment: @Chuck you said in the first comment if I have looked at ICP algorithms. I forgot to ask what/how I could make use of them? I have a brief idea of how ICP works and have used available online implementations. Just to confirm, ICP still gives me a transformation, right? How do you mean I should look at ICP algorithms?

Comment: I'm saying you could use ICP to compare two point clouds and the magnitude of translation and rotation could be a metric you use to compare the two. You could also the nearest neighbor algorithm that is used by ICP to calculate RMS distance between the clouds and use that as a metric. ICP algorithms should also have explanations of how they handle outliers - if there is a narrow object in your scene and it renders in one frame but not the other, how should that affect the quality of your match? It all depends on how you intend to use the comparison results - "good enough" or something more?